# Using NOT in quick filters

Tags: usability, filter, user-centered-design

We have an option in our system to use a quick filter as "not"
See example:

[image]

We have a keyboard shurtcut to use this option but the downside is that users are not aware of that option.
Second is that visually it is probably not good to use strikthrough as it affects filters readability.

Do you have some ideas on how to visualize this in a better way?
And how to expose this option?

Comment: The problem is that you're using an **antipattern**, this is NOT the way to use pills in filters. The whole idea is that you only show those pills you're using to filter results, and the only available interaction should be the *"delete"* action. Hence, since it's an antipattern, you might expect problems (as you already have found). If you want to keep the filters visible at all times, you should use `checkboxes` which users can enable and disable without any cognitive effort.

Comment: It may be, the colors can help too. And, as @Devin told, try to use `checkboxes`, possibly, for most frequently used keywords.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is more clear than explicit text.

Why don't you say exactly that:

> Filtering **`"Design"`** **`not "New"`** **`not "In progress"`**

Maybe color code the tags for additional effect.

I don't know how do users add those filters, but maybe it's good idea to do two lists:

> Including **`Design`**
>
> Excluding **`New`** **`In progress`**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's necessary to interfere with the text. Using show and hide icons would be enough:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, It should be clear to the users that "Phase - is not - New, In Progress" I'm not sure it's not confusing, I would assume it means something like show/hide values.